# “None of who’s” vs. “none of whose”

Tags: pronouns, possessives, determiners, grammatical-case

Is the following phrase grammatical?

> I seem to recall three people, none of who's names I can remember.

Comment: ...three people, whose names I can't remember!

Comment: Alternately (and awkwardly) "...three people, none of the names of whom I can remember."

Comment: That's a lot of syntax to pied pipe just to confess ignorance.

Comment: @JohnLawler what are you saying?

Comment: I'm saying that _I seem to recall three people. I can't recall any names_ does the job without any syntactic heavy lifting, on your part or -- more importantly -- on the part of your addressee.

Comment: @JohnLawler How is this syntax complicated?

Comment: Related to and possible duplicate of one or another of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64320 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9557 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21078 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4786 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/175230 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/126994 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8296 — in no particular order except at first.

Comment: As asked, your question is Off-Topic Proofreading.  Please see our Help Center for how to write a good question.

Answer (score 10):

No. It is "whose".

"Who's" is the contracted form of "who is", which doesn't make sense in this context and is also ungrammatical..

"Whose" is the ***possessive*** form of "who". I'll take the chance and guess that was meant.

Comment: Please do not answer trivial General Reference questions without any research shown.

Comment: @tchrist give it a rest

Comment: However, note that this is **only** true in writing. In speech _who's_ and _whose_ are pronounced identically, and distinguished, if at all, only by syntax, like _bear_ (v), _bear_ (n), and _bare_. And -- surprise! nobody ever gets confused in speech. How come they get confused in writing? Because it's not a distinction we're used to making -- like apostrophe's it's inaudible -- and it requires an abstract (and incorrect) analysis of how language works in order to master. This is not a trivial General Reference question.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I can hear the apostrophes...in the screams of my grade school English teacher.